# How do I uninstall python from OSX Leopard so that I can use the MacPorts version?

Tags: python, macos, osx-leopard, macports

I want to use the macports version of python instead of the one that comes with Leopard.

Comment: You should not uninstall default python from OS X, this may make your system unstable because Python is an important OS component. Instead you can use macports to add other instances of python.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have both installed:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ which python2.5
/opt/local/bin/python2.5
```

I also added the following line to my `.profile`:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Comment: What should the new python at /opt/local/bin look like? I installed Python via MacPorts and it had no effect on any of the python* files in /opt/local/bin. They're all symlinks to the system Python. This is on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 29):

Don't. Apple ships various system utilities that rely on the system Python (and particularly the Python "framework" build); removing it will cause you problems.

Instead, modify your PATH environ variable in your `~/.bash_profile` to put `/opt/local/bin` first.

Comment: i think this is true also of different linux distro's, various library /package/software installers rely on the perl, python , ruby factory installed interpreters, you should leave them there, symlink around them

Answer (score 20):

Use the [python_select](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=python_select) port to switch python interpreters.

```
sudo port install python25
sudo port install python_select
sudo python_select python25
```

This will symlink `/opt/local/bin/python` to the selected version. Then export `PATH` as described above.

Answer (score 17):

`python_select` is now deprecated, use this instead:

```
sudo port select python python26
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of uninstalling the built-in Python, install the MacPorts version and then modify your `$PATH` to have the MacPorts version first.

For example, if MacPorts installs `/usr/local/bin/python`, then modify your `.bashrc` to include `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't uninstall it since many scripts will expect python to be in the usual places when they do not follow  convention and use `#!/usr/bin/env python`. You should simply edit your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` so the macports binaries are the first in your path.

Your `.profile` should have this line:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

If not, add it in, and now your shell will search macport's `bin/` first, and should find macports python before system python.

Answer (score 3):

The current Macports installer does the .profile PATH modification automatically.