# MacPorts on Snow Leopard: Python install seems to succeed but doesn't install a non-system Python

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, macports

I've installed Python via MacPorts. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118813/how-do-i-uninstall-python-from-osx-leopard-so-that-i-can-use-the-macports-version) question, the files in /opt/local/bin should run the "correct" Python version. However, all those files are symlinks to:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/
```

Running them directly from that folder (using no symlinks) runs an Apple build of Python!

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan  6 2011, 13:25:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

For comparison, running /usr/bin/python shows a slightly different version:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

They're both Apple builds! How do I install the correct version?

Comment: They're not both Apple builds.  They were both built with Apple builds of GCC.

Comment: Try `homebrew` instead. It's what macports should have been. /aside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think it is running the build you want.**

macports install every thing in /opt/local. So `/opt/local/bin/python is a macport distribution`.

/usr/bin/python is pre-install python distribution that comes with mac os x.

The following line, is an information about gcc build which is used for building macport python distribution.

> [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)]

If you have multiple versions of macport python installed, you can select the version using python-select

```
sudo port install python-select sudo
python-select python26
```

Also to ensure that you use macport python you could add the following to the PATH

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: sudo port select python python26

Answer (score 3):

There are no "Apple builds" except the system Python (which is 2.6.1 on Snow Leopard, afai can deduce). The ports install seems to have worked as expected in this case. The reference to Apple is a reference to which GCC that was used.