# Error Importing scapy into Python interpreter on OSX [MacPorts install]

Tags: python, macos, macports, scapy

I installed scapy via MacPorts as recommended here in the official scapy documentation: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#mac-os-x

It works just fine when I run scapy from the command-line.

However now I can't seem to import scapy into the Python interpreter or in a python script, here's the error.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan 31 2013, 22:54:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scapy
```

I have also tried with Python2.5, doesn't work either.

```
Python 2.5.6 (r256:88840, Aug  5 2011, 03:29:42) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scapy
```

I think it has to do with the path somehow, but I don't know where to edit those on Mac, especially that I installed scapy from MacPorts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macports installs everything to `/opt/local`. So I bet if you run `/opt/local/bin/python`, you'll be able to import `scapy`.

If you need `scapy` to be importable from the default Python installation, you'll need to install it into that Python installation (instead of the other, Macports, Python installation).

Relavent information from other answers:

- [Running Macports Python #1.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4623591/99377)
- [Running MacPorts Python #2.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/118820/99377)

Comment: That solved the problem, I use the version of python in /opt/local/bin/python instead. Thank you!