# Python/Macports import error - scapy

Tags: python, macports, scapy

I had some free time tonight, and decided to try out a tool called wifijammer (https://github.com/DanMcInerney/wifijammer) that I read about on reddit a while back.

I cloned the project off gituhub, chmod'd the python file, and installed scapy using macports. However, when I run the wifijammer.py file, it gives me:

```
ImportError: No module named scapy
```

And references the line:

```
from scapy.all import *
```

I googled around and found that there is a difference between v1.x and v2.x which requires scapy or scapy.all — I tried both without success. I also check my version with,

```
sudo port installed | grep -i scapy
```

Which spits back:

```
scapy @2.2.0_1 (active)
```

I'm really not too sure where to go with this one. I can post any additional information that people may need. Help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Importing scapy into Python interpreter on OSX \[MacPorts install\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820811/error-importing-scapy-into-python-interpreter-on-osx-macports-install)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! Finally found the source of the problem. Y'all can read about it and its solution here: [Error Importing scapy into Python interpreter on OSX [MacPorts install]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820811/error-importing-scapy-into-python-interpreter-on-osx-macports-install?rq=1)